# How to upgrade android2.2 to android3.2?

Tags: android, upgrade

I have viewsonic android 2.2 tablet. Now i want to upgrade my tablet. Is it possible to do that? If it is possible means how can i do this. Can anybody tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=841

Comment: I don't think ViewSonic allows the upgradation.... so try rooting the Tablet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Find the device here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/index.php?s=029cd73571e995f5b034d6ffd1cf5cc7) and check if it can be upgraded or rooted. If it cannot be upgraded then find a root that suits you and root it. Keep in mind that companies releasing Android devices know what versions of the system the device can handle well enough, so consider this when rooting the device because it may run slower with a newer Android version. Rooting, though, has the benefit of allowing you to overclock the proccessor which may be needed in order to get a good result out of your rooted update. Remember rooting may break the company warranty (pretty sure it does) and may potentially cause some poblems. Hopefully if you follow the instructions of the forums closely you will be able to do it right and you can always downgrade back to the original if I am not mistaken! Anyway, good luck if you plan on rooting and be careful! ;)